# Draw a circuit with a voltage divider, two comparator ICs, LDR sensors

Tags: digital-logic, adc, comparator, dac, ldr

I got this last question to practice for my exam and I got stuck. The question is draw a circuit with

- a voltage divider circuit,
- two Comparator ICs,
- LDR(Light Dependent Resistor) sensor

Outputs:

- If LDR at dark, comparator 1 = high and comparator 2 = low.
- If LDR under the light, comparator 1 = low and comparator 2 = high.
- If LDR at dark, the value of R in LDR becomes higher.

Assume that the range of R value in LDR = 0-100 kohm.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkYag.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's a built-in schematic tool with a button on the editor toolbar. Place all your components onto the schematic and make an attempt at the wiring. We'll help you along.

Comment: @Transistor Hi. i've added schematics as I understand it.

Comment: Your practice question doesn't call for a NOT gate, and you don't need one. You also haven't drawn any sort of voltage divider there.

Comment: @brhans I just fixed it. Is that correct? If its not, then can you please list some points that I need to know? Thanks before

Comment: Vast improvement. But your ratio of VR1 ro R1 is way off, and you still need another (fixed) voltage divider...

Comment: @brhans the question didnt say anything about the ratio of resistor. Is there any ideal ratio for resistor value in voltage divider? And.. What is that another fixed voltage divider? Thank you.

Comment: The schematic as it is now **will not work**. The comparators have their inputs connected to Vin and another voltage which has a value between Vin an ground (0 V). A comparator's decision level is at the point where the voltages are equal. That situation (equal input voltage) is never reached in this schematic. Hint: look up "Wheatstone bridge".

Comment: @EvangelinaTessiaP Well, you do know that the LDR lives in the range of 0 to 100 kΩ, this means that with 10 kΩ as you have now, then the node between the LDR and the 10 kΩ will be between \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{in}/11\$. If you use 100 kΩ instead of 10 kΩ the node will be between \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{in}/2\$. It's up to you if you want to use a division by 2 or 11. Or division by 3 for that fact. I would use division by 3 and then make another voltage divider to get 2/3 of your voltage supply and..... some other stuff..

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie wheatstone bridge is a little bit too much for Evangelina I think. No need to get all "fancy" for this problem. Just add another voltage divider and you're set.

Comment: @HarrySvensson just adding another voltage divider (like you suggest) would in fact make it a Wheatstone bridge :-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've just revised it. How it is now?

Comment: After another schematic update (add R2, R3 and R4), yep there you go :-) That **will** work. Small detail: there is no need for any input voltage so you can rename Vin to Vdd or "supply"

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you so much for helping me :))

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Heh, you're actually right. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faQ4a0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Redrawn OP schematic (at the time of writing).*

Olin seems to have got you thinking and you have accepted his answer which indicates that you have enough information to complete your task. I'll just offer a couple of points.

- By inverting the orientation of the comparitors we can untangle all the wire crossings except one. This makes the schematic much more legible.
- You can now label your R2, R3, R4 divider junctions with their voltages. e.g., \$ \frac {2}{3} V+ \$ and \$ \frac  {1}{3} V+ \$.
- With that information you can now work out at what voltages each comparator will switch.

Note that because of R3 you have the comparators switching at different voltages. You probably want to remove it.

Finally, many comparators have open-collector outputs and need a pull-up resistor on the output.

Answer (score 2):

First, think about how you'd achieve *one* of the compartor outputs.  That really shouldn't be hard.

Use the LDR as part of a resistor divider.  That gives you a voltage that is a function of the light level.  Now you compare that voltage to a threshold.  The result is a digital high/low signal that indicates whether the light level is above or below the threshold.

To get the second digital output, you could just duplicate the comparator part of the above, or invert the output of the first comparator.

### Added in response to schematic

It looks like you're going for the second option I mentioned, which is to invert the first signal to make the second.  That's fine.

However, think about what the polarity of a comparator is?  What is the effect of flipping the signals to the two inputs?

### Added 2

You are now using the first option, which is also fine.  However:

Think about what the voltage range out of the divider will be over the full brightness range.

Follow the polarities carefully.  Separately analyze what happens when the LDR is seeing dark and seeing light.  Solve for all the voltages in each case and see exactly what the comparators will do.

Think about what exactly you are trying to accomplish with R3.

I didn't want to say this outright yesterday because I wanted you to think about it.  However, this circuit is still wrong.  This is the same circuit shown more cleanly in Transistor's answer.  I don't want you or anyone else getting the impression this is a valid solution to the problem.  This circuit doesn't meet the specs in at least two different ways.

Comment: I just fixed my answer. Please correct me. Thanks before :)